# Where is the Windows source code for Android adb?

Tags: android, windows, adb

I am trying to understand how Android `adb.exe` works on Windows.  I found the following source code branch:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/

However, based on a quick glance within the `adb.cpp` file, this seems to be the Linux branch.  Where is the Windows version?  (Or am I wrong?)

PS: Information on how one could navigate [android.googlesource.com](https://android.googlesource.com/) will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [stated](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-platform/ErIdj_RKnRs/gRAUN4Djs0QJ) by Romain Guy:

> It's in the Android source tree:
> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/adb

Inside `adb.cpp` there are some references to Windows like this one:

```
// In the past, reading from a pipe before the child process's C Runtime
// started up and called GetFileType() caused a hang: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/02/10243553.aspx#10244216
// This is reportedly fixed in Windows Vista: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2009703
// I was unable to reproduce the problem on Windows XP. It sounds like a
// Windows Update may have fixed this: https://www.duckware.com/tech/peeknamedpipe.html
```

Here is explained how to build Android SDK or just the tools (including adb)  for Windows:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/docs/howto_build_SDK.txt

Comment: Thank you.  The how-to-build link you posted provided the missing piece to the puzzle. It says: **"To build the Android SDK for Windows, you need to use a *Linux* box."**  So it seems the code is written in a portable manner for all three OS'es.

Answer (score 0):

The source code directory of `adb` now seems to have changed to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/adb/

not https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/adb